# Starting multiple IE URLs in new parent instances

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer

Hoping I can get a nudge in the right direction here. What I am trying to do is launch 2 URLs in their own parent instance so that they do not interact with each others Cache. Everything I am doing so far opens 1 parent IE and then runs the pages under that. I know I can shell it out, but I have specific IE settings per page I need to pass.

```
    Dim IE1 As New InternetExplorer
    With IE1
        IE1.Top = 0
        IE1.Left = 0
        IE1.Width = 700
        IE1.Height = 800
        IE1.Visible = True
        IE1.Navigate2("URL1")


    End With


    Dim IE2 As New InternetExplorer
    With IE2
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 700
        .Width = 700
        .Height = 800
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate("URL2")
    End With

End Sub
```

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: The third (optional) parameter of `Navigate` and `Navigate2` represents the target frame: `_blank`, `_parent`, `_self` and `_top` or the name of an existing frame.

Comment: Still loads up both pages in the same process of IExplorer

Comment: whether you want to open the IE browser using VBA or Vb.net application? From your code it seems that you are using VBA.